# Setting Up Redis-py in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python, redis

I am trying to install redis-py or redis-rb (preferably redis-py) but none of the sites I visit and the blogs I have read have provided a solution that has been satisfactory. Can anyone please tell me how I can set it up. It is quite urgent.
I am currently running on python 2.7.2+ on ubuntu 11.10
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pip install redis` or `easy_install redis`. Use `apt-get install python-pip` to install pip or `apt-get install python-setuptools` to install easy_install.